# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown' in decision trees

Tags: python, tree, decision-tree

```
drugTree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[68], line 1
----> 1 drugTree.fit(X_train, y_train)

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py:889, in DecisionTreeClassifier.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input)
    859 def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, check_input=True):
    860     """Build a decision tree classifier from the training set (X, y).
    861 
    862     Parameters
   (...)
    886         Fitted estimator.
    887     """
--> 889     super().fit(
    890         X,
    891         y,
    892         sample_weight=sample_weight,
    893         check_input=check_input,
    894     )
    895     return self

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py:224, in BaseDecisionTree.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input)
    221 self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
    223 if is_classification:
--> 224     check_classification_targets(y)
    225     y = np.copy(y)
    227     self.classes_ = []

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py:218, in check_classification_targets(y)
    210 y_type = type_of_target(y, input_name="y")
    211 if y_type not in [
    212     "binary",
    213     "multiclass",
   (...)
    216     "multilabel-sequences",
    217 ]:
--> 218     raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

expecting:
Decision Tree Classifier
DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=4)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).